# MySQL select min price from 2 connected tables

Tags: mysql, e-commerce, min, price

I'm working on custom e-commerce solution but I don't know how can I select MIN price from 2 columns on 2 different tables.

```
TABLE: shop_products
id
title
price
price_sale

TABLE: shop_products_variants
id
product_id
price
price_sale
```

So table shop_products hasMany shop_products_variants. You can specify price or price_sale on shop_products table but you can also specify price or price_sale for custom variant. 
I need to select products with minimal price for each product (including product variants). I was able to find MIN price in variants but I'm not able to combine MIN price from shop_products and MIN price from shop_products_variants.

```
CASE WHEN price_sale IS NOT NULL THEN price_sale ELSE price END AS price_min
```

I would appreciate any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join 'shop_product' table and 'shop_products_variants' table, after it you can find minimal price in result set. For example:

```
SELECT sp.id,
       sp.title,
       MIN(LEAST( IFNULL(sp.price_sale, sp.price, sp.price_sale), 
                  IFNULL(spv.price_sale, spv.price, spv.price_sale) 
       )) AS min_price
FROM shop_products AS sp
LEFT JOIN shop_products_variants AS spv ON shp.product_id = sp.id
GROUP BY sp.id,
         sp.title
```

Comment: Thank you Maxim this works. But there is one more issue when all product variants have price NULL and price_sale NULL but shop_product has defined price I get NULL value AS min_price. It should return sp.price value

Answer (score 0):

Maxim's answer works just with small fix for case when price & price_sale in products_variants are NULL.

```
MIN(LEAST( IFNULL(shop_products.price_sale, shop_products.price),
           IFNULL(
               IFNULL(shop_products_variants.price_sale, shop_products_variants.price), shop_products.price)
           )
   ) AS min_price
```